# How to configure Yii's UrlManager for OpenSearch controller

Tags: php, url-routing, yii

I am trying to add OpenSearch functionality to my Yii application and have trouble configuring the UrlManager to route a search request to the right controller (called *query* in this case) and method (called *index*). The search works great if there are no white space in the search words. Whenever someone searches for more than one word, the UrlManager cannot find the controller and method to handle the search.

The url in the search.xml file that triggers the search is like this:

```
<Url type="text/html" template="[pathToMyApp]/application/index.php/query/{searchTerms}"/>
```

And my UrlManager is configured like this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
  'urlFormat' => 'path',
  'rules' => array(
     '<_c:(name|tag)>s/*' => '<_c>/index',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     'query/suggest/<needle:\w+>'=>'query/suggest',  // used to route OpenSearch JSON suggestions - works
     'query/findbox'=>'query/findbox',  // routes search queries from a form in the application - works
     'query/<needle:\w+>'=>'query/index', // works only for search strings with no white space
  ),
  'showScriptName' => true,
),
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the second rule to the bottom?

Comment: @Jon - sadly doesn't fix my problem, but it is better there in anyway, ie more specific matches first.

Comment: On second thought: in `query/<needle:\w+>`, the `\w+` part will stop matching at the first non-word char (e.g. a space). Maybe changing the `\w` to something more forgiving (e.g. `[\w ]` for starters) will do the trick?

Comment: Excellent! Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it to show the problem has been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in `query/<needle:\w+>`, the `\w+` part will stop matching at the first non-word char (e.g. a space). Changing the `\w` to something more forgiving (e.g. `[\w ]`) will probably do the trick.